# cakephp element error (Element Not Found)

Tags: cakephp

i've just started using cake 2.2 (usually i use 1.3) and i have a problem with view elements. i need to create an element for my application, being used in homepage and some other places.

i think i've done all the things right:

- i have an action in the controller (ads/latest)
- i've created the element in *app/View/Elements/latest.ctp*
- i call it in the home.ctp like this: `<?php echo $this->element('latest'); ?>`

but it gives me this error `"Element Not Found: Elements/latest.ctp"`

Comment: probably a typo. Check the name and extension of latest.ctp

Comment: I think element file is not saved with the correct extension. otherwise you are writing in a correct way.

Comment: ok...i think it was due to the new file function of netbeans which force you to create a .php file and then rename the extension, but it doesn't work. you must copy and paste another .tcp file. hope it helps someone! anyway thanks to you ;)

Comment: In netbeans you can create a new php file and name it latest.ctp at creation already, no need to rename after first creating it as .php

Answer (score 0):

A few things could cause that:

- there's a difference between the filename and the `element()` call
- the element call should NOT include ".ctp"
- the element file has an incorrect extension (should be `.ctp`)
- file permissions on the element are incorrect and don't allow access
- the path to your element is incorrect (ie it's in a folder, but you're not specifying that in the call)

If you pass all those tests, you should be good to go and not get any errors.